# Confused between Language & Culture! :(

Tags: localization, symfony1, doctrine, internationalization

I'm repeatedly getting confused between Language & Culture in Symfony.
- I'm setting culture as (en_US) which I guess is correct
- but translation files are created for a language (en)
- also, when using translation in the database, the lang=en

I have a model whose definition is as follows:

```
Option:
  package: Options
  tableName: Com_Options
  actAs:
    I18n:
      fields: [name, tooltip]
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(2)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      unsigned: true
#      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
      notblank: true
    tooltip:
      type: string(100)
    sequence:
      type: integer(1)
      unsigned: true
      range: [0,255]
```

This class is referred by several other classes.
When I try to print the name as $refObj->Option->Name I get nothing. When I check the queries, I see that 3 queries are fired in all.

```
1) to get refObj
2) to get Option
3) to get Translation
```

But the real problem is that for 3, there is no language parameter in the query.

> > > I wonder how it will get the translated name? Current value of sf_culture: en_US
> > >
> > > Is there another way to access the 'name' according to user's language?
> > >       Or do I need to write custom queries on every model?
> > >
> > > Is the problem because autoincrement is OFF, or because Im using a package?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you also have **sf_default_culture** set to en_US?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: a very tedious & costly method, but works:

```
$class->relation->Translation[$lang]->property
```

If you wish to read directly from database

```
$q = Table::getInstance()->createQuery('a')
        ->select('a.id, t.name')
        ->leftJoin('a.Translation t')
        ->where('t.lang = ?', $lang);
return $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_NONE);
```

If you use XLIFF files, you need not pass culture/language

```
__('text which is translated in the XLIFF for user\'s culture');
```